# jsonGet method of UnifiedJedis return byte array value end with .0

Tags: java, redis, jedis

```
HostAndPort config = new HostAndPort("localhost", 6379);
UnifiedJedis client = new UnifiedJedis(config);
Object object=client.jsonGet("StandaloneResponse:9b970b5f-32c2-4265-92cb-9af9d6707782");
System.out.println(object);
```

output-

{exchangeId=9b970b5f-32c2-4265-92cb-9af9d6707782, createdTimestamp=Nov 23, 2022 4:14:01 PM, variables={OrderBy=, ErrorResponseMessage=, ErrorResponseCode=, Filter=, Expand=, Skip=0.0, Select=, Payload=[], ReturnValue=[60.0, 63.0, 120.0, 109.0, 108.0, 32.0, 118.0, 101.0, 114.0, 115.0, 105.0, 111.0, 110.0, 61.0, 34.0, 49.0, 46.0, 48.0, 34.0, 32.0, 101.0, 110.0, 99.0, 111.0, 100.0, 105.0, 110.0, 103.0, 61.0, 34.0, 73.0, 83.0, 79.0, 45.0, 56.0, 56.0, 53.0, 57.0, 45.0, 49.0, 34.0, 32.0, 115.0, 116.0, 97.0, 110.0, 100.0, 97.0, 108.0, 111.0, 110.0, 101.0, 61.0, 34.0, 110.0, 111.0, 34.0, 32.0, 63.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 60.0, 83.0, 116.0, 117.0, 100.0, 101.0, 110.0, 116.0, 32.0, 120.0, 109.0, 108.0, 110.0, 115.0, 58.0, 101.0, 100.0, 109.0, 61.0, 34.0, 104.0, 116.0, 116.0, 112.0, 58.0, 47.0, 47.0, 115.0, 99.0, 104.0, 101.0, 109.0, 97.0, 115.0, 46.0, 109.0, 97.0, 103.0, 105.0, 99.0, 115.0, 111.0, 102.0, 116.0, 119.0, 97.0, 114.0, 101.0, 46.0, 99.0, 111.0, 109.0, 47.0, 101.0, 100.0, 109.0, 34.0, 32.0, 120.0, 109.0, 108.0, 110.0, 115.0, 58.0, 110.0, 115.0, 49.0, 61.0, 34.0, 104.0, 116.0, 116.0, 112.0, 58.0, 47.0, 47.0, 115.0, 99.0, 104.0, 101.0, 109.0, 97.0, 115.0, 46.0, 109.0, 97.0, 103.0, 105.0, 99.0, 115.0, 111.0, 102.0, 116.0, 119.0, 97.0, 114.0, 101.0, 46.0, 99.0, 111.0, 109.0, 47.0, 101.0, 100.0, 109.0, 34.0, 32.0, 120.0, 109.0, 108.0, 110.0, 115.0, 58.0, 120.0, 115.0, 61.0, 34.0, 104.0, 116.0, 116.0, 112.0, 58.0, 47.0, 47.0, 119.0, 119.0, 119.0, 46.0, 119.0, 51.0, 46.0, 111.0, 114.0, 103.0, 47.0, 50.0, 48.0, 48.0, 49.0, 47.0, 88.0, 77.0, 76.0, 83.0, 99.0, 104.0, 101.0, 109.0, 97.0, 34.0, 32.0, 120.0, 109.0, 108.0, 110.0, 115.0, 58.0, 120.0, 115.0, 105.0, 61.0, 34.0, 104.0, 116.0, 116.0, 112.0, 58.0, 47.0, 47.0, 119.0, 119.0, 119.0, 46.0, 119.0, 51.0, 46.0, 111.0, 114.0, 103.0, 47.0, 50.0, 48.0, 48.0, 49.0, 47.0, 88.0, 77.0, 76.0, 83.0, 99.0, 104.0, 101.0, 109.0, 97.0, 45.0, 105.0, 110.0, 115.0, 116.0, 97.0, 110.0, 99.0, 101.0, 34.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 60.0, 114.0, 111.0, 119.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 60.0, 70.0, 105.0, 101.0, 108.0, 100.0, 115.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 60.0, 73.0, 68.0, 62.0, 52.0, 53.0, 60.0, 47.0, 73.0, 68.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 60.0, 78.0, 97.0, 109.0, 101.0, 62.0, 116.0, 101.0, 115.0, 116.0, 32.0, 100.0, 97.0, 116.0, 97.0, 60.0, 47.0, 78.0, 97.0, 109.0, 101.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 9.0, 60.0, 47.0, 70.0, 105.0, 101.0, 108.0, 100.0, 115.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 9.0, 60.0, 47.0, 114.0, 111.0, 119.0, 62.0, 13.0, 10.0, 60.0, 47.0, 83.0, 116.0, 117.0, 100.0, 101.0, 110.0, 116.0, 62.0], ReturnHTTPStatusCode=0.0}, status=0.0}

Data is proper in the RedisDb, but when I am accessing it using jedis-4.2.3.jar library then it is showing like above out put. **I don't want the byte array data end with .0**. Please help me here if any one has any idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

Jedis 4.2.3 is using both Gson and org.json:json libraries to process JSON. Both of these upcast any numerics to `double` and that is what you are seeing.

There are a few ways I can think of to get them as `byte`s:

1. It is possible to cast your `object` to `LinkedHashMap`. Traverse it and change the *recognized* `double` values (e.g. under `ReturnValue`) to `byte` values.
2. Get `ReturnValue` separately:

```
Byte[] returnValue = client.jsonGet("<KEY>", Byte[].class, Path.of(".variables.ReturnValue"));
```

3. Execute a raw command and parse the result by yourself:

```
Object object = client.executeCommand(new CommandArguments(JsonProtocol.JsonCommand.GET).add("<KEY>"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are right this is due to the Gson. I did following change in code and now it is working fine. " new GsonBuilder().setObjectToNumberStrategy(ToNumberPolicy.LONG_OR_DOUBLE)
       .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new DoubleSerializer()).setPrettyPrinting().create() "

Comment: @DattatraySatpute You can post your solution as an answer including the changes and where you are making those changes. This will help if someone else faces same issue.